# gradle project build directory does not exist

Tags: gradle, war, output-directory

Trying to create a properties file (foo.properties) and add it to the root of a war.

```
apply plugin: 'war'

task createProperties {
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("${project.buildDir}/foo.properties");
    ...
}

war {
     dependsOn createProperties
     from "${project.buildDir}/foo.properties"
     ...
}
```

What went wrong:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> E:\app\build\build.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Do I need to create the build dir?

for war, is there an output dir for webapp? (sourceSet: src/main/webapp)
It is better to create the `foo.properties` directly under the webapp outputDir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
 war {
      from createProperties
      ...
 }
```

this will add an implicit dependency on the createProperties task automatically, so no need for a dependsOn.

For this to work you need to specify the output of your `createProperties` cleanly like

```
task createProperties {
    outputs.file("$buildDir/foo.properties")
    doLast {
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("$buildDir/foo.properties");
        ...
    }
}
```

But actually you should use a task of type `WriteProperties`, that looks cleaner and is better for reproducible builds. Something like this:

```
task createProperties(type: WriteProperties) {
    outputFile "$buildDir/foo.properties"
    property 'foo', 'bar'
}
```

If your properties are calculated dynamically and not statically (which I assume, otherwise you could simply create the file manually) you should also set the dynamic parts as inputs of the task, so that the tasks up-to-date checks work properly and the task is only run when necessary because some input changed.

Comment: what is the difference between $buildDir and ${project.buildDir}? Thanks.

Comment: There is none, you just don't need to qualify the call. You can as well use `${project.buildDir}`, they are really identical in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
task createProperties {
    doFirst {
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("${project.buildDir}/foo.properties");
        ...
    }
}
```

Explanation with an example :

```
task foo {
    println 'foo init line'
    doFirst {
        println 'foo doFirst'
    } 
    doLast {
        println 'foo doLast'
    }
}

task bar {
    println 'bar init line'
    doFirst {
        println 'bar doFirst'
    } 
    doLast {
        println 'bar doLast'
    }
}
```

Now for the commande `gradle clean bar`, you'll get as  otput :

```
foo init line
bar init line
:clean
:foo
foo doFirst
foo doLast
:bar
bar doFirst
bar doLast
```

The `clean` step went after the init step hence in your case, the `foo.properties` is erased before trying to be found.

Comment: does the $project.buildDir is not the same as $buildDir in this ocasion?

Comment: Same scope, same value, the `project.` can be omitted here